# How to send array collect in a script that is programmatically injected into a web page via chrome.tabs.executeScript() to another JS file

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am making a chrome extension that reads the DOM of the website that my school posts our grades on, and, based on that information, the user can calculate how well they need to do on a test to achieve a grade. For example, say the user has a 95.6, an A, but needs to get a 96.5 to get an A+ for the term. He would select how the test is weighted and how many questions it will be/was, and the program will output the minimum number of correct answers they need/needed. I'm reading the DOM of my school's website via chrome.tabs.executeScript (content.js), and it does exactly what I need it to do. However, I need to send the array of information that it collects from the to another JS file (calc.js) so the dropdown on that page can be updated with the categories from the DOM of the grading website. I've seen questions that seem to use the chrome API to send messages, but I don't really understand how to use them or if that is how I should be transferring my information. Here is my code.

manifest.json

```
 {
            "manifest_version": 2,
            "name": "Calculate My Grade",
            "version": "1.0",
             "content_scripts": [{
                "matches": ["*://grading.myschoolscounty.net/*"],
                "js": ["/js/content.js"]
            }],
            "browser_action": {
                "default_icon": {
                    "16": "/images/icon_16.png",
                    "24": "/images/icon_32.png",
                    "64": "/images/icon_64.png"
                },
                "default_title": "Calculate My Grade",
                "default_popup": "/html/popup.html"
            },
            "permissions": ["activeTab"]


        }
```

content.js

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(, "category_ar", , write2);

var category_ar = 0; //getCategoryAr(getAllRows(getMainTable(getAllTables())));

function getAllTables() {
    return Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("info_tbl"), 0);
}

function getMainTable(all_tables_ar) {
    for (var idx = 0; idx <= all_tables_ar.length - 1; idx++) {
        for (var idx2 = 0; idx2 <= all_tables_ar[idx].rows.length; idx2++) {
            for (var idx3 = 0; idx3 <= all_tables_ar[idx].rows[idx2].cells.length - 1; idx3++) {
                if (all_tables_ar[idx].rows[idx2].cells[idx3].innerHTML == "Assignment Type" && all_tables_ar[idx].rows[idx2].cells[idx3 + 1].innerHTML == "Weight") {
                    return all_tables_ar[idx];
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

function getAllRows(main_table) {
    return main_table.rows;
}

function getCategoryAr(row_ar) {
    var category_ar = new Array();
    for (idx = 1; idx <= row_ar.length - 2; idx++) {
        category_ar.push(new Array(row_ar[idx].cells[0].innerHTML, // Assignment Tyoe
            row_ar[idx].cells[1].innerHTML, // Weight
            row_ar[idx].cells[2].innerHTML, // Points
            row_ar[idx].cells[3].innerHTML)); //Points Possible
    }
    return category_ar;
}
```

popup.js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    document.getElementById("calc_btn").addEventListener("click", click);
});

function click(e) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file:"/js/content.js"});
}
```

calc.js

```
 function receiveArray(){};
 function doStuffWithDropdown(){};
```

calc.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/navbar.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/calc.css" />
</head>

<body>
        <script src="/js/content.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/calc.js"></script>



    <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
        <a id="back_btn" href="popup.html"> &larr;</a>
        <a id="title">Calculate My Grade
    </div>


    <div id="calc_div" class="display_page">
        <!--Input for Grade Calculator-->
        <form>
            Questions Correct/Points:<br>
            <input type="number" name=""><br> Number of Questions/Number of Points :<br>
            <input type="number" name="">
            <select id="dropdown" name="Category">
                <option>test</option>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </div>
</body>

</html>

popup.html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/navbar.css">
</head>

<body>
        <script src="/js/content.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/calc.js"></script>

    <script src="/js/popup.js"></script>
    <!--Menu Buttons to select Grade Calculator or Gpa Calculator-->
    <div id="button_menu_div" class="display_page">
        <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
            <a id="gpa_btn" href="gpa.html">GPA Calculator</a>
            <a id="calc_btn" href="calc.html">Calculate My Grade</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should take a look at the documentation, specifically at [Message Passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging)

Comment: @Titus, I have, but I don't entirely understand what's going on, and I'm not sure if that's what I should be using

Comment: Those are the only ways you can pass data from a content script to a background script. Also, if you declare `content_scripts` in your extension's manifest, you don't need to use `chrome.tabs.executeScript` because the script will be injected automatically when a page from the `matches` array is opened.

Comment: @Titus Ok, I will fix my manifest. Do I have to send my message to a background script, or can I send it to any js file as long as there is a listener for it? Can I send any kind of object?

Comment: The manifest is good as it is. If you only want to inject `content.js` into webpages that match this pattern `*://grading.myschoolscounty.net/*` you can remove the `chrome.tabs.executeScript(...)` call.

Comment: @Titus Oh, Ok, I misunderstood you, will fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to retrieve some data from a opened webpage when a button in the extension's popup window is clicked.

If that is the case, you can do something like this:

Content Script:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if(request.cmd == "getData"){
        sendResponse(extractDataFromThePage());
        // instead of "extractDataFromThePage()" you can use "getCategoryAr(getAllRows(getMainTable(getAllTables())));" if that is how you extract the data.
    }
});
```

Popup:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    document.getElementById("calc_btn").addEventListener("click", click);
});
function click(){
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({cmd: "getData"}, function(response) {
       console.log("data from content script", response);
    });
}
```

What this does is to send a message to the background script when the `calc_btn` in the popup is clicked. When the content script gets this message, it extracts the data from the page and sends it back to the popup.

Comment: Ok, I see, I thought the content script would be sending the information and the popup would be receiving it, but it's more like the popup sends a request and the content script responds to it. That was the part that was confusing me. Thank you so much for your help!